# Error when loading Viewer v3.2.1

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm getting an error when loading the Forge Viewer v3.2.1.

I've just tried with v3.1.1 and it's working fine.

The error thrown in the console is:

```
ERROR TypeError: WGS is undefined

Autodesk.Viewing.Private.initializeLegacyNamespaces@https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=v3.2.1:12:10590
e@https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=v3.2.1:42:7197
j@https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=v3.2.1:42:5825
```

It was working fine yesterday, and I haven't touched my code, so I assume it is a bug.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The url you should use is https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=3.2.1. My apps are using this and it works fine.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm using and the error above appears. I'll revise the code and all my configuration to see if something is wrong in there. I'm going to try to reproduce it on a clean new project.

Comment: I'm getting the same error on a clean project, is it possible to send you the project so you can test it?

Comment: You can put it on github and send the link or if you want to keep it private PM me: philippe.leefsma"at"autodesk.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm loading this version like this:

https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=3.2.*

Add the script like that it is working for me.

Comment: You didn't test in an Angular app... did you? The issue is specific to angular, another argument in favour of using React I guess :D